# how to reverse/decompile marshal.loads() in python

Tags: python, unmarshalling, decompiling, deobfuscation

So i have this:

```
import marshal
code = b'c\x00\x00\x...'
exec(marshal.loads(code))
```

and i want to see the code behind it:
but when i replace the **exec()** with **print()** i just get this:

```
<code object <module> at 0x000001E56EA9E660, file "Specter", line 1>
```

what i tried:

- put the bytecode into a .pyc file and trying to decompile it with pycdc
- using a [unmarshal script](https://gist.github.com/painor/17d18aeb8ae90f9355bf520a22104002), but it was for python 2.7
- using [python-xdis](https://github.com/rocky/python-xdis)

> my python version is 3.9.13